# Better UI in Tizen app

Tags: user-interface, tizen, tizen-native-app

I tried **Tizen Web** application development. Now I want to move to **Native** application development. I can't find a good resource for making good UI in native. 
Moreover, Tizen Native API seems complex to me. I think it is not Developer friendly API at all. Source codes become unmanageable as all of the implementations remain in a single file.

Comment: Please post your source code and describe how it does not meet your needs. SO is not a place to debate the merits of a tool.

Answer (score 2):

For Tizen UI, Firstly do study on EFL and gather basic knowledge on it. Check the following links to learn Tizen UI design from the scratch

1. https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.1/org.tizen.guides/html/native/ui/efl_n.htm
2. https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4.0/org.tizen.ui.practices/html/native/efl/ui_containers_n.htm
3. https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/ui-practices/native-application/efl/ui-components/mobile-ui-components?langswitch=ko
4. https://developer.tizen.org/development/ui-practices/native-application/efl/ui-containers/creating-ui-screen-layouts?langswitch=en&langredirect=1
5. https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/native/2.3.0/org.tizen.mobile.native.appprogramming/html/guide/ui/widgets_guide.htm

Also there is a nice book on Tizen development with lots of example. Download the "**Guide to Developing Tizen Native Application**" book 
from the following link. You will find this book very helpful for tizen development learning.

Book Link: https://wiki.tizen.org/wiki/Books

Answer (score 0):

How about C#?

Samsung has released a preview of Visual Studio Tools for Tizen, which will enable .NET developers to build apps for Tizen.

Official Developer Site
https://developer.tizen.org/development/preview

Getting Started with Visual Studio Tools for Tizen (Preview)
https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Connect/2016/200

Comment: Currently C# for Tizen development is in preview version, So i think we have to wait till final Tizen.Net version release. Samsung may release the final version at the beginning  of 2017.

Currently you can test C# app in Emulator only. You cant run your Tizen.Net app in real devices right now as current Tizen devices are not .Net enabled.